# OnClick / OnTouchListener not working in draw on top view

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a service which draws a view on top of the phone. 
But i cannot click oder touch this view with a onTouch or onClick Listener. 
Any ideas why this isn't working? 
Doesn't matter on which view i bind the OnClickListener.. It's not working.

```
protected WindowManager mWindowManager;
protected View mQueueStatusView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mQueueStatusView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_queue_indicator, null);
    mQueueStatusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    RelativeLayout rlRoot = (RelativeLayout) mQueueStatusView.findViewById(R.id.rl_root_queue_indicatior_container);
      rlRoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("OVERLAY", "CLICKED!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    });
    rlRoot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("OVERLAY", "CLICKED!!!!!!!!!");
            return false;
        }
    });
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;


    mWindowManager.addView(mQueueStatusView, params);



}
```

Comment: This smells like something that should never be allowed to work ;)  Why would I want your service intercepting clicks to apps?  Are you writing a key logger?  ;)

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE is that getting applied to the same view you have click and touch listeners on?

Comment: Omg what a silly copy paste mistake. -.- Thank u Xjasz!!
It's working now

Comment: @Fabian i have the same requirment to catch event on overlay but events are not captured (click/touch).Checked the params many times but i dont know whats going wreong.Can you share any link for tutorial or anything?So that i can check what is missing.thanks in advance